# How to implement client-server undo functionality?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I am working on a php application (with Zend Framework and Doctrine 2).

The special problem that occured recently, is that I have to copy some data from a database table and send it to the client.

When the client saves, the copy of the data keeps in the database (the data **must** be persisted in the Database before sending it to the Client. Storing it temporarily would not be an option). If the client doesn't save the copy,it has to be deleted.

I thought of an implementation of the **command pattern**, which would be the common solution to any undo process. But how to trigger the UNDO command when the client disconnects, closes his browser or another error happens?

Is there any approved solution to this problem?

Comment: i excuse my "bad english" that someone took as reason to vote this question down. English is not my mother tounge, but im keen to express my question as good as i can.

Comment: This is something for a maintainance job. Such job periodically cleans every left overs from session that are not valid any more. Typically such job is run from a cron daemon or 'poor mans cron'.

Comment: Just transact the whole process. If the client bombs before the commit then the rollback will happen automatically.

Comment: Yeah, the transaction would be my common approach, but in this special case, while the client edits the data, an ajax datagrid already wants to work with the data in the database..

Comment: @arkascha: I hoped there was an alternative to a batch-job :(

Comment: You could have a table with a 'job started' and a 'job completed' for each client process. If the 'completed' field was null after a certain gap from 'started' then delete the data.